# Controller Inside a Controller in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, methods, controller

I'll try to explain this as best as I can..

What is the best structure (when using the MVC approach through CakePHP) to structure Administrator logic?

I want to be able to visit:

- `www.website.com/admins/` --> Shows a Dashboard view Easy to implement: "Index" Method in the "Admins" Controller.
- `www.website.com/admins/customers` --> List of Current customers. Easy to implement: "Customers" Method in the "Admins" Controller.
- `www.website.com/admins/customers/add` --> **How would this work?!**
- `www.website.com/admins/customers/view/1` --> **Or this?**

I know my approach is wrong, since I should probably have a Controller for each area ("Customers", "Orders", "Employees") so each can have their own View, Edit, Add methods.. but how would I tie them all under the "Admins" Controller since I want them all to be under `www.website.com/admins`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 2 solutions

1. using admin plugin
2. using admin routing (i recommend this)

   for using the admin routing you can use this documentation
   http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

   also you can use of console for creating admin routing

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I went with the Admin Routing method and almost got it to work. My only issue is getting the IsAuthorized method to redirect properly.. any advice? I've described it above!

Comment: you can use this variable in the admin controller `public $uses = array('Employee', 'Orders', 'Customers');` so you can use all of these models in your admin controller and with your logic start developing view in your app. (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

The misconception here seems to be that the URL must strictly follow the `/controller/action/parameters` pattern, which is not true. It's only the default and you can change it to whatever you want using the [router](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).

[The Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) even has an example for this exact case:

> Many applications require an administration section where privileged
>   users can make changes. This is often done through a special URL such
>   as `/admin/users/edit/5`. In CakePHP, prefix routing can be enabled from
>   within the core configuration file by setting the prefixes with
>   Routing.prefixes. Note that prefixes, although related to the router,
>   are to be configured in `app/Config/core.php`:
>
> ```
> Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
> ```
>
> In your controller, any action with an `admin_` prefix will be called.
>   Using our users example, accessing the URL `/admin/users/edit/5` would
>   call the method `admin_edit` of our `UsersController` passing 5 as the
>   first parameter. The view file used would be
>   `app/View/Users/admin_edit.ctp`.

In practice this means that all admin actions are in separate controllers ("Customers", "Orders" etc) along with non-admin actions. Using a separate admin controller is theoretically possible but somewhat more complicated.

Comment: Juhana, sorry just another question.. I've got this all working exception when checking for authorisation..

When someone who doesn't have authorized (not logged in or logged in account doesnt have adequate clearance) the AuthComponent should redirect to website.com/users/login but it goes to: webiste.com/admin/users/login instead.. which yields the "Missing Method" error.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking, Routing works great as suggested by Juhana but to get the authorization redirect working properly in my Auth Component in my AppController, I had to insert this:

```
 'unauthorizedRedirect'    => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login',
                'admin' => false
            ),
```

This fixed the issue when someone tried to access `www.website.com/admin/orders` it would redirect to `www.website.com/admin/users/login` when I needed it to redirect to `wwww.website.com/users/login`